# (Andorid Instant)Try to get json/xml content with http(s) request

Tags: http, kotlin, android-instant-apps

Currently, I am developing Android instant app. 
In the feature module, I would like to get json/xml content with http(s) call.

Based on my research, I found 2 ways to do so.

first

```
val url = URL("https://json or xml url")
val connection: HttpURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
val response = connection.responseCode
```

second

```
val result = URL("https://json or xml url").readText()
```

Both does not work.

I use valid url. I typed the url in web browser and able to get what I want.

I add internet connection in manifest xml file as well(base module, feature module). Still the result is unfruitful.

Can you tell me how I can get json/xml content using http(s)call in android instant app(kotlin)?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get some error? Or what do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Can you try HttpsURLConnection? Only HTTPS is allowed in instant apps, I know, even though your actual url is https itself.

Comment: I did try and catch syntax. I got null in e:exception.message.....